# Update value of a p:diagram from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have implemented the sample diagram from the primefaces showcase. I have another button which clears the elements, and I want this to also refresh the actual value of the diagram itself. This would either require me to 1. somehow trigger a refresh from another xhtml element (the button), or 2. set the value of the diagram from JavaScript. The problem here is that this would require me to get the diagram model object from the managedbean. From what I've found you can call on a managedbean method using remoteCommand, but this doesn't let you return a value from the bean itself back to the JavaScript.

Essentially, would it be possible to edit the following to make the commandButton (or use any other type of component) refresh the diagram's value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateModel() {
        //refresh diagram
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    /* snip css */
</style>
<h:body>
    <p:diagram id="diagram" value="#{diagramFlowChartView.model}" style="height:600px" styleClass="ui-widget-content" />
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton style="margin: 3px;" icon="fa fa-key" value="Refresh" onclick="updateModel();"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

It doesn't matter whether this will be done through the JS block that I set up, or if there is a way to force the diagram element to refresh it's value in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces component `p:diagram` uses [jsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demo/flowchart/index.html) JavaScript library.
jsPlumb provides powerful API but Primefaces JSF library supports only basic functions out-of-box (at least in version 6.1). 
If you want to use jsPlumb in its full power, you will need to dig deeper into native JavaScript API.

So depending on how you implemented your function "which clears the elements" there are 2 refresh/update approaches:

**1. Client side approach**

First add Primefaces `widgetVar` to your `p:diagram` like this

```
<p:diagram id="diagram" widgetVar="diagramWidget" value="#{diagramFlowChartView.model}" style="height:600px" styleClass="ui-widget-content" />
```

then in your updateModel() JavaScript method you can get jsPlumb object and manipulate with data (and UI rendering). For example,

```
function updateModel() {
        //refresh diagram

        //get jsPlumb instance
        var jsPlumbObj=PF('diagramWidget').canvas;
        //log in JS console so that you can see all available properties and methods of jsPlumb
        console.log(jsPlumbObj);
        //delete all connectors in your flow chart
        jsPlumbObj.deleteEveryEndpoint();
        //do other stuff
        ....
    }
```

After executing this, you will see that all connections between elements are deleted.
But be aware that you only manipulated with client side data while server side model data is still untouched.

**2. Server side approach**

In case you cleared/deleted elements by modifying model on server side, then I suppose you have changed bean scope from `RequestScoped` to `ViewScoped` and that you added managed bean's method similar like this

```
public void clearElements(){
    //clear model elements
    model.clear();                        
}
```

In this case there is no need for JavaScript at all. You only need to slightly modify your `p:commandButton` like this

```
<p:commandButton style="margin: 3px;" icon="fa fa-key" value="Refresh 
server" actionListener="#{diagramFlowChartView.clearElements()}" 
update="diagram"/>
```

and you will see you diagram refreshed (it will be empty in this case).

**By the way...**
You actually you can use `p:remoteCommand` to call managed bean method and return value back to JavaScript.

Add this method to managed bean

```
public void doSomethingWithModel(){
    //for example, delete 1st element
    model.getElements().remove(0);      
    //serialize model and push it to client
    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();        
    rc.addCallbackParam("returnedObjectValue", model);
}
```

add this JS method inside xhtml page

```
function getResultFromManagedBean(xhr, status, args){
   var returnedValue = args.returnedObjectValue;
   //you will see how Primefaces DefaultDiagramModel looks like in JS console after you deleted 1st element
   console.log(returnedValue);
   //do something with it
   //...
}
```

add remoteCommand

```
<p:remoteCommand name="modifyModel"
     action="#{diagramFlowChartView.doSomethingWithModel()}"
     oncomplete="getResultFromManagedBean(xhr, status, args);" update="diagram"/>
```

and finally modify **p:commandButton** like this

```
<p:commandButton style="margin: 3px;" icon="fa fa-key" value="Refresh" onclick="modifyModel();"/>
```

You will see that 1st element disappeared and that JS console shows only 4 elements inside your model on client side. Now you will be able to use `returnedValue` in JavaScript on the way you want.